# Blender 2.69 Baking issue

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I have spent a few days with this issue trying to solve an issue for a work project that needs to be ready in less than a week. I normally dont have a need to bake textures onto models however it is required for this project.

Basically I have followed every written and video tutorial I could find and tested them on a basic cube in blender, and every time I bake the texture to the cube it comes out wrong. Massive bleeding around the UV, the actual texture I created in GIMP is drastically shrunk, and is entirely on one face of the mesh.

And just a moment ago I decided to bake it again, without changing any settings and the texture magically rearranged itself to fit properly with some bleeding. I am very confused and need to know how to properly bake textures for real models for work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think what are calling "bleeding" is actually the [*Margin*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Bake).

Comment: It looks like you have the hang of it. The problem the first time is likely the uv-mapping of the mesh you are baking from. Do you really want to do a "full render" bake? Normally you would do diffuse, normal or ambient occulusion.

Comment: Gandalf3 - Thanks, I'm not used to baking textures. Never needed to until now.

Comment: Gunslinger - I dont understand what you mean about the uv-mapping. Even though they look like different uv-maps, they are actually the same .png file. For some reason when I baked it the second time it baked it properly. And as far as "Full Render" goes, I have to use full render for the simulation software that the actual models will be imported to.

Comment: You must haven't chosen the UV map set that you really want to use. Just try deleting either of the two UV set, I'm sure you'll see what's happening.

Comment: @Leon Cheung, thanks for the idea. I just tried what you said and it didnt work. :( I get either a full red cube, which isnt what I want, or I get a red cube with a micro sized version of the UV texture.

Comment: In that case, please bring your "patient" up here via sites like www.pasteall.org, which would be straight forward to help you more.

Comment: @Leon Cheung http://www.pasteall.org/blend/26111 There be the sick one lol. I think I've either been starring at my computer too long and over looked something small, or I'm just way too tired.

Comment: @Leon Cheung Also, if blender by chance gives you a warning of possible missing plugins dont worry about it. The plugin is an exporter for a flight simulator called X-Plane. I'm having other issues that I will be calling them about tomorrow.(And in the "Bake" settings, I have to use "Full Render" for the XPlane export.)

Comment: If I bake directly with your file without any tweaking, it would fail, because the image on which you are baking is used by the object itself, which caused a circular reference, so you do need to create another image, or duplicate the current one (*test.png* in this case). However, if you actually mean the "bleeding" issue, as gandalf3 said, the Margin value setting in **Bake** panel is what you need.

Comment: @Leon Cheung Thank you for taking a look at the blend file. However I think I'm too tired at the moment to understand. Ill have to look at it again tomorrow. Also, I hate sounding like an absolute moron, especially since I am very familiar with blender, I just havent had a need to actually bake textures until this simulator project at work. But if its possible (I also hate sounding like I'm begging), would you be willing to look at a video of my terrible performance of attempting from scratch, while following a written tutorial and tell me where I went wrong?
I am way too tired for this haha

Comment: In a nut shell, my mind is a little weird. Ask me to design and animate something complex, no problem. Ask me to make something simple, and my brain dies. lol

Comment: Sure. let's check the video. Since the discussions here is over extended a bit, please try to earn at least 20 reputation around to continue this in chat room. PS: I need your confirmation here: What's the real problem now, bleeding or UV or something?

Comment: It is a little over extended. I can certainly try to reach 20 reputation. As for the confirmation, primarily the problem is UV/Baking. There is a secondary problem, however I will be calling the company that developed the software I am importing textured models into tomorrow. For now, I need to get some sleep for work tomorrow. The video has been uploaded to Youtube, and is being processed. Since I cannot give you a direct link yet, this is the youtube channel it will be viewable on in about an hour or so(hopefully). It will be the only video there. https://www.youtube.com/user/wraithofthemist

Comment: If you haven't already solved your problem by now, perhaps you could try it with out the large face overlapping the E?